# Distribute associative array elements into groups with a maximum sum per group

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, mathematical-optimization, integer-arithmetic

I need to split my associative array into bunches of not greater than 50 in each bunch.  Multiple elements may be pushed into a given group to ensure that a group reaches 50 before starting a new group.

Sample input:

```
$array = [
    '5' => 142,
    '2' => 57,
    '18' => 37
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    ['5' => 50],
    ['5' => 50],
    ['5' => 42, '2' => 8],
    ['2' => 49, '18' => 1],
    ['18' => 36],
];
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Or do you expect people to code this for you?

Comment: Be more clear of what you want to do and also post what you've tried so far...

Comment: Apologies but I think it's a clear query where you have input and output both. I am doing the coding myself so if you people could help suggest some logic before, it would be great. Asking if someone has done the similar work before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just mind games

```
$line = [];
// Invert array
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
   $line = array_merge($line, array_fill(0, $v, $k));
}
// Split and count occurrences
$res = array_map('array_count_values', array_chunk($line, 50));
print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/952867)

Comment: this is really clear, but you need a lot of memory if the values are large

Comment: I would need this to run a single time only with a high availability server in term of memory.

Comment: The explanation could be more generous and the demo link is dead, but this is a very clever approach.  uv.  It can be written all in nested functions this way: https://3v4l.org/QbuZL

Answer (score 2):

To create an array where the sum of each entry would not exceed a given amount, you can use an iterative approach.

Let's start with an empty array and a variable representing the working index of that array. As we go through the input array, we add the maximum possible remaining quantity to the new array. If we reach the limit, we increment the index variable. And we continue as long as the input array has not been completely browsed.

Code:

```php
const MAX_SUM = 50;
$total  = []; // Store the new data
$curKey = 0;  // Store the current key of $total array.
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    while ($value) {
        // Get the current sum for the current key:
        $curSum = array_sum($total[$curKey] ?? []);

        // If the max was reached, we can go to the next key:
        if ($curSum == MAX_SUM) $curKey++;

        // Now, compute if the value to add (max to reach 50);
        $add = $value + $curSum > MAX_SUM // If above,
            ? MAX_SUM - $curSum           // got only the difference,
            : $value;                     // else, use the full value.

        // Add the value
        $total[$curKey][$key] = $add;

        // Finally, remove what we added just before.
        $value -= $add;
    }
}
print_r($total);
```

Outputs :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [5] => 50
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [5] => 50
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [5] => 42
            [2] => 8
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [2] => 49
            [18] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [18] => 36
        )
)
```

See also a the [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831404/9193372) of @mickmackusa.

Answer (score 1):

My train of thought for this task aligns with @Syscall's "push & consume" approach.

1. Iterate the input array to access the keys and values.
2. Use an inner loop to repeatedly process the current value until it is fully consumed by subtraction.  Only break the loop upon the value being reduced to zero.
3. With each pass of the inner loop:

   - Calculate the current total of all values in the group, then
   - Find the lesser integer value between how much room is left in the group and how much is left in the value; push that integer into the group with the current key; then subtract that integer from the current value, then
   - Increment the group key if the current group has reach its limit
4. Repeat until all input elements are reduced to zero.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/s8GMC))

```
$groupLimit = 50;  // declare as a variable to avoid "magic numbers" in code

$result = [];
$groupKey = 0; 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    while ($value) {
        $sum = array_sum($result[$groupKey] ?? []);                           // get group sum
        $value -= $result[$groupKey][$key] = min($groupLimit - $sum, $value); // push key with limited value; decrease value
        $groupKey += ($sum + $result[$groupKey][$key] === $groupLimit);       // only increment group key if at $groupLimit
    }
}
var_export($result);
```